# Regex to match entire words containing only specific characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find all the words that have the specific characters(letters, numbers and special characters) and ignore the rest.

Here's my [expression](https://regex101.com/r/RnZz2s/2):

```
/[cwh]\w+/ig
```

**Example:**

- Match:  **watch**, because `c`, `w` aswell as `h` is present in that word
- Skip:   **Welcome**, because only `c` and `W` is present

The expression need match case insensitive.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Wouldn't "Welcome" still match because it has a lowercase "c"?

Comment: I have edited your post to make your point clear to fellow users. If I've misunderstood your goal, rollback it.

Comment: @Kinduser Thanks, that's helpful. I can't tell if it's supposed to contain all of the letters or just some.

Comment: @musicnothing case-insensitive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use positive lookaheads:

```
\b(?=\w*c)(?=\w*h)(?=\w*w)\w+
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/RnZz2s/3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your match rules are - since both **watch** (lowercase w) and **Welcome** (lowercase c) would match the characters in your list. But

```
\w*[cwh]\w*/g
```

is probably what you're after.

This will match zero or more word characters, one character from your list, and zero or more word characters in a case sensitive fashion (*w* is distinct from *W*) globally (multiple matches possible per line).